# How to properly set focus to a div element in React using createRef

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, create-ref

I have a react app that I am working on, and currently, I have a custom-built dropdown that I want to open/close when a user clicks on the trigger(the arrow button), close it when a user selects an option, or close it when a user clicks outside the displayed component.

Here is my code:

For the sake of simplicity, I only added the code that I want help with.

```
class NavBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showCurrencies: false,
    };

    this.handleShowCurrencies = this.handleShowCurrencies.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.currencyRef = createRef();
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.state.showCurrencies) return this.currencyRef.current.focus();
  }

  handleShowCurrencies = () => {
    this.setState({
      showCurrencies: !this.state.showCurrencies,
    });
  };

render() {
  <div className="currency-switch" onClick={this.handleShowCurrencies}>
    {currencySymbol}
    <span>
      <button>
        <img src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/arrow.png`} />
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
  {this.state.showCurrencies ? (
    <div
      className="dropdown"
      tabIndex={"0"}
      ref={this.currencyRef}
      onBlur={this.handleShowCurrencies}
    >
      {currencies?.map((currency) => (
        <div
          key={currency.symbol}
          className={`dropdown-items ${currencySymbol === currency.symbol ? "selected" : "" }`}
          onClick={() => changeCurrencySymbol(currency.symbol)}
        >
          {`${currency.symbol} ${currency.label}`}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  ) : null}
}
```

Currently, directing focus to a div element is working fine, and clicking outside the element as well. However, clicking back on the trigger or even selecting an option is not closing the div element. It seems like it is rendering twice(take a closer look on the console): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ObxU__SbD_Upxr6qcy5eYO4LSy6Mzq9C/view?usp=sharing

Why is that happening? How can I solve it?

P.S: I don't often ask on StackOverflow, so am not familiar with the process. Please bear with me. If you need any other info, I will be more than happy to provide it.

Comment: Could you please format the code slightly better (indents), especially the render section so that's easier to read?

Comment: Of course! Do you mean more indentation?

Comment: @IvanSilkin, I edited the question, how about now? is it better?

Comment: It's better now for sure, what about "addEventListener", does react use that? In raw js that should be the recommended way to add handlers on wherever element on the page.

Comment: @IvanSilkin, no we don't use them. [Handling events in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html). In this case, the event listeners are `onClick` and `onBlur`